# Shutown Spring when DB is lost

Tags: java, spring, hikaricp

#### Use case

Our spring-boot-backend (v 2.3.1) using a postgres-database with HikariCP as connection pool.
The application is online and a admin accidentally kills the database.

#### Expected behavior

Spring notice that the connection to DB was lost. The application will gracefully shutdown.

#### Actual behavior

Spring is still running. All methods, which needs the db, ending up in exceptions.
To recover a complete good state, we need manually to restart spring.

**Notes**
We have a lot of async workers and they cannot recover correctly, when the database is going back online.
And docker/kubernetes will notice when the application shutdown and can automatically restart it.

#### Question

How can I reach the expected behavior?
Sadly I found nothing similar in the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the hints from @Zubair I build a new small solution.
Iam using the [Spring-Actuator-package](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.3.4.RELEASE), because they have some ready classes for this use-case.

All what I need was a `HealthIndicator`-Bean, like this

```java
@Bean
public HealthIndicator dataSourceHealthIndicator(final DataSource dataSource) {
  return new DataSourceHealthIndicator(dataSource, "SELECT 1;");
}
```

and scheduled watcher (because HikariCP nor the HealthIndicators has any events).

```java
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000L)
public void checkDBHealth() {
  final Status status = this.dataSourceHealthIndicator.health().getStatus();
  if (!Status.UP.equals(status)) {
    log.error("DATABASE IS OFFLINE! SHUTTING DOWN!");
    System.exit(1);
  }
}
```

I hope that will be useful for others.

#### Edit

I had to change the config of HikariCP. Otherwise the health-checker waiting almost endless for database-connection.

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
  final HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
  // default settings with user, password, jdbc, ...
  config.setInitializationFailTimeout(1000);
  config.setConnectionTimeout(1000);
  config.setValidationTimeout(1000);

  return new HikariDataSource(config);
}
```

Comment: Also, mention maven dependency for actuator which you used...will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

If its spring 2.0, you may call the shut-down actuator from some monitoring service.

Comment: Hm. It's possible to use a bean as monitoring-service?

Comment: You can expose a Rest-endpoint and the functionality can be provided by a bean. I think yes, a bean can ping on some url / endpoint.

Comment: see if you check app/db health from http://localhost:8080/actuator/health and can check ...if the health is no OK call the shudown endpoint from actuator...I suggest see actuators

Comment: Is there not a direct way? Something like this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/jdbc/DataSourceHealthIndicator.html

Comment: may be try this in application.properties: management.health.db.enabled=true

Comment: This article will also help: https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-actuator-database-health-check.html

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I'll try something and will post (hopefully) a answer soon.

Comment: Iam done. Thanks for the advice with actuator, that helps a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the actuator default provided health indicators in your property files and replace your custom [DatasourceHealthIndicator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.2.13.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/jdbc/DataSourceHealthIndicator.java) by register it as bean.

```java
@Bean
public DataSourceHealthIndicator dataSourceHealthIndicator(){
   return new DataSourceHealthIndicator(dataSource, "SELECT 1");
}
```

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomHealth implements HealthIndicator {

   private final DataSourceHealthIndicator healthIndicator;

   @Override
   public Health health() {
      // ...
      return Health.status(healthIndicator.health().getStatus()).build();
   }
}
```

And set your properties like this.

#### application.yaml

```yaml
management:
   health:
      db:
         enabled: false
```

#### application.properties

```
management.health.db.enabled: false
```